# Set Theory: Proving Statements About Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be arbitrary sets taken from the positive integers.

I have to prove or disprove that: $$ \text{If }A ∩ B ∩ C = ∅, \text{then } (A ⊆ \sim B) \text{ or } (A ⊆ \sim C)$$

Here is my disproof using a counterexample:

If $A = \{ \}$ the empty set,
$B = \{2, 3\}$,
$C = \{4, 5\}$.

With these sets defined for $A, B,$ and $C$, the intersection includes the disjoint set, and then that would lead to $A$ being a subset of $B$ or $A$ being a subset of $C$ which counteracts that

if $A ∩ B ∩ C = ∅$, then $(A ⊆ \sim B)$ or $(A ⊆ \sim C)$.

Is this a sufficient proof?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of any set so you do not arrive at a contradiction.  I'm not sure if the "~" is significant in your notation but ignoring it, the claim is clearly false.  Just take A,B, and C to be the singletons {1}, {2}, and {3} respectively.  The intersection of the three is empty and none of these set s is a subset of the others.

Comment: the ~ means complement, so it is important

Comment: Ok, so ignore my first counterexample.  But the empty set is still a subset of every set.  How about this.  Take A,B, and C to be {1,2}, {2,3}, and {1,3}.  If I understand the question correctly, this should work.

Comment: Right, so why can't I use that to disprove this

Comment: Sorry, I may still be confused about the question but to produce a counterexample (at least as I understand the question) you need three sets which do not all contain a common element, and the first set, A, cannot be a subset of ~B or ~C.  Since the empty set is a subset of everything, it is a subset of ~B and ~C which is actually consistent with the result.

Comment: Oh ok. Now I understand. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Regarding the question title: you cannot "prove" a set, that verb does not fit with that direct object. Only theorems, statements, propositions, lemmas, etc. can be proved.

Comment: What would be a more appropriate title?

Comment: @Krysten: about the time you left that comment, I already edited the title to make it more in line with typical mathematical English.

Comment: lol thanks. now i know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\{2,3\}$, $B=\{1,3\}$, and $C=\{1,2\}$.

The intersection of the three sets is empty.  But none of them is a subset of the complement of another.

By symmetry, it is sufficient for example to show that $A$ is not a subset of the complement $B^c$ of $B$.

Note that $B^c$ consists of all integers except $1$ and $3$.  Since $A$ does contain $3$, $A$ is not a subset of $B^c$.

**Comment**: As has been pointed out in a comment by @Joe, the empty set is a subset of every set, so setting $A=\emptyset$ cannot give you a counterexample, whatever be the choice of $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Isn't the intersection of A and B 3 and the intersection of A and C is 2?

Comment: Ahh, now I see how it works. Very Clever.

Comment: Yes, but $A\cap B\cap C$ is the intersection of the *three* sets, and there is no number which is in *all three* sets.

Comment: How did you know to pick those element for A, B, and C? Was it just trial and error?

Comment: It was clear that we would have a counterexample if $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ are each non-empty. So I wanted to arrange for that, and have $A \cap B \cap C$ empty. I like symmetry, hence the example.

Comment: Symmetry meaning each set has one element that is not in the other?

Comment: @Krysten: More than that. If you permute $A$, $B$, and $C$ in any way, the basic pattern remains unchanged. Thus we get two bonuses: (i) if $X$ and $Y$ are two distinct sets chosen from $A$, $B$, $C$ then $X$ is not a subset of $Y^c$ and (ii) checking the property for one pair effectively checks it for all $6$ possible ordered pairs $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

As another counterexample, let $A=\mathbb{N}$, and $B$ and $C$ be disjoint sets with at least one element each.

Elaborating: On the one hand, since $B$ and $C$ are disjoint,
$$
A \cap B \cap C = \mathbb{N} \cap B \cap C = B \cap C = \emptyset.
$$
On the other hand, $A = \mathbb{N}$ is not contained in the complement of $B$, since $B$ is not empty, and the same for $C$.